# What is Imran Khan's position on Balochistan?

Tags: pakistan, imran-khan

I have tried to find the answer myself and read the two following links:

- [Imran Khan and Balochistan](http://thebalochistanpoint.com/imran-khan-and-balochistan/)
- [Imran Khan says Pakistan Army killed innocents in Bangladesh, Balochistan..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXTic84Za7E)

The first link has some relevant information but it is not comprehensive. The second implies that he denounces atrocities against Baloch people. But they don't cover the whole topic.

The question is, what is Imran Khan's position on Balochistan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what would count as "cover[ing] the whole topic", but [here](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1041967/imran-khan-vows-to-fight-for-rights-of-baloch/) is an article with a few direct quotes.

> Imran said he will fight for the rights of Balochistan, claiming he
>   did not have an idea how rights of smaller provinces were suppressed
>   until his party formed government in Khyber-Pakhtunkhwa.
>
> “[The] K-P does not get its due share of water, electricity and gas
>   from the centre,” he said. “A water channel supposed to be built in
>   1992 has not been built by the government, yet.”
>
> [...]
>
> Imran assured the people of Balochistan that his party will never use
>   force against them.
>
> “I will never start a military operation in your province but will
>   respect your right to protest,” he said, claiming that he understood
>   why Balochis were struggling for their rights.

Another quote earlier in the article lists five very specific demands of resources that the federal government should commit to the region.